# Disable link after child window is open, restore once child window is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent

My client has a link on their website which opens a customer service chat window in a popup. They are seeing users clicking the chat link multiple times, which opens multiple chat sessions, and it is throwing off their stats. I need to disable the link when the chat window is opened, and restore it when the chat window has been closed. I can't modify/access child window.

The original link looks like this:

```
<a class="initChat" onclick="window.open('https://chatlinkhere.com','chatwindow','width=612,height=380,scrollbars=0'); return false;">
```

I figured the best thing to do would be to store the `window.open()` as a variable in a function:

```
function openChat() {
    child = window.open('http://www.google.com', 'chatwindow', 'width=612,height=380,scrollbars=0,menubar=0');
}
```

and change the link HTML to

```
<a class="initChat" onclick="openChat();">
```

Note: Ideally, I'd like to detect the original onclick's value, and store it in a variable. Something like:

```
  jQuery('.initChat').find().attr('onclick');
```

But I'm not sure how to store it and then call it later.

Next I need to run a check to see if the chat window is open or not:

```
timer = setInterval(checkChild, 500);

function checkChild() {
    if (child.open) {
        alert("opened");
        jQuery(".initChat").removeAttr("onclick");
        jQuery(".initChat").css("opacity", ".5");
        clearInterval(timer);
    }

    if (child.closed) {
        alert("closed");
        jQuery(".initChat").attr('onclick', 'openChat(); checkChild();');
        jQuery(".initChat").css("opacity", "1.0");
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}
```

Note: the alerts are just there for testing.

And add the new function to the link

```
<a class="initChat" onclick="openChat(); checkChild();">
```

And once the chat window is closed, I need to restore the onclick attribute to the link (is there an easier way to do this?)

Fiddle demo is here -> http://jsfiddle.net/JkthJ/

When I check Chrome Console I'm getting error 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined`

***UPDATE***
Whoever left me the answer in http://jsfiddle.net/JkthJ/2/ thank you very much it works! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I got to finally work:

```
    <a class="initChat" onclick="checkWin()"></a>


    <script>
    var myWindow;

    function openWin() {
        myWindow = window.open('https://www.google.com', 'chatwindow', 'width=612,height=380,scrollbars=0');
    }

    function checkWin() {
        if (!myWindow) {
            openWin();
        } else {
            if (myWindow.closed) {
                openWin();
            } else {
                alert('Chat is already opened.');
                myWindow.focus();
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need is open pop up if already open then foucus on pop up or noyhing should happen

you can rewrite your function as

```
var winPop = false;  
function OpenWindow(url){  
  if(winPop && !winPop.closed){  //checks to see if window is open  
    winPop.focus();  // or nothing 
  }  
  else{  
    winPop = window.open(url,"winPop");  
  }  
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working in Chrome, IE, or Firefox. I've added new snippet to my question using your answer, maybe I'm implementing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

just do it in a simple way. disable the mouse events on anchor link after child window open.

**css**

```
.disableEvents{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

**js**

```
var childWindow;

$('a').on('click',function(){
  childWindow = window.open('_blank',"height:200","width:500");
  $(this).addClass('disableEvents');
});

 if (typeof childWindow.attachEvent != "undefined") {
      childWindow.attachEvent("onunload", enableEvents);
 } else if (typeof childWindow.addEventListener != "undefined") {
    childWindow.addEventListener("unload", enableEvents, false);
}

 enableEvents = function(){
      $('a').removeClass('disableEvents');
  };
```

**update**

your child window is plain html page. Do the changes in child window html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
window.opener.enableEvents(); //it calls enableEvents function 
}
</script>
</head>
<body onunload="myFunction()">
<!--your content-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks great chandu, but I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: childWindow is not defined`. Also, it doesn't look like `pointer-events` has great support, and I'm sure the client's users probably use outdated browsers =/ http://caniuse.com/pointer-events

Comment: I forgot to define child window. Now I have added

Comment: Now I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attachEvent' of undefined `

Comment: put all the code into $(document).ready(){} function.If its not works we need to change the html code

Comment: Still not working, but thanks for trying. I pasted all my html including your script into http://jsfiddle.net/JkthJ/3/

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned I can't modify/access child window